# Regex match word with alphabets + number but not just number

Tags: python, regex

For example i've

```
Jack_50 * 50
Debby_35 * 15
Ross_10 * 24
```

I want to get just

```
Jack_50, Debby_35, Ross_10
```

I tried

```
[\w._]+
```

It gives even the *50, *15, *24

```
[^\d\W]+
```

This gives just `jack,debby, ross`

even tried https://www.autoregex.xyz/home

Comment: Why not `[a-zA-Z]+_\d+`?

Comment: Or `", ".join(i[:i.find(" ")] for i in s.splitlines())`

Comment: Note that the `re.M` flag must be used with `^`, otherwise you'll only get the first match (or none, if the input doesn't start with a word-character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

s = 'Jack_50 * 50   Debby_35 * 15  Ross_10 * 24'
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z_]+\d+', s)
```

Output:

```
['Jack_50', 'Debby_35', 'Ross_10']
```

You can also try on every separate string like `Jack_50 * 50`

**Explained**
`r'[a-zA-Z_]+\d+'`: matches one or more characters from `a-zA-Z_` followed by one or more numbers (`\d+`). This doesn't match space or *.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression:

`^\w+`

The above expression will match one or more occurrences of word characters (alphabets capital or small, digits and underscore) at the starting of the line.